# ConTeXt: Art book (persistent left margin et al)

Tags: margins, context

I am trying to create a book displaying artworks using ConTeXt in (what I thought would be) a very simple layout: One image per page, sized according to orientation, with artwork title, year etc underneath, aligned to the right border of the image.
However I am stuck at the most basic level: I always get a small margin to the left of the image (ConTeXt source below). 
How can I make sure the image is placed at the exact location I want it to appear (the layer below is set to x=0,y=0 to check that it actually is placed relative to the page border) ?
(I have used LaTeX in the past for scientific publications, but thought ConTeXt woul be the better choice, due to Lua and out-of-the-box support for embedding color profiles/PDF/X-3 generation).

```
\setupinteraction
[
    title=Artist Name, subtitle=002-012, author=Artist Name, keyword={{art, photography}, digital}
]

\setupbackend[
    format=PDF/X-3:2002, profile=AdobeRGB1998.icc, intent=Blurb_ICC_Profile.icc
]

\definepapersize[Blurb_12in_x_12in][width=12in, height=12in]

\setuppapersize[Blurb_12in_x_12in]

\setuplayout[
 topspace=0in,
 backspace=0in,
 cutspace=0in,
 bottomspace=0in,
 header=0in,
 footer=0in,
]

\setupexternalfigures[directory={images, C:/Art/imgs}]


\setuppagenumbering[state=stop]


\starttext

\definelayer[img_horizontal]
\setlayer[img_horizontal][x=0in,y=0in]{
\setupTABLE[frame=off, width=10.8in, offset=0mm]
\bTABLE
\bTABLEbody
\bTR \bTC \externalfigure[LKCHCZFCWFCCHCKJFCHCZFCWFCCZCKJK.png][width=10.8in] \eTC \eTR
\bTR[align=left] \bTC  Image Description, 2008 \eTC \eTR
\eTABLEbody
\eTABLE
}
\flushlayer[img_horizontal]

\stoptext
```

Comment: Instead of using `\setupsomething[\n key=value, key=value \n]` (`\n` mean new line), use `\setupsomething[\n key=value, key=value, \n]` (Note the comma after the last option. Otherwise, the last value is taken as `value\n` rather than `value` and can lead to some hard to diagnose bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you define your layer introduces spurious spaces, which you see on the left. If you add percent signs at the end of these lines:

```
\setlayer[img_horizontal][x=0in,y=0in]{%
\setupTABLE[frame=on, width=10.8in, offset=0mm]%
\bTABLE
...
```

this space disappears. (At least I hope this what you are trying to achieve, your description "at the exact location I want it to appear" is not very precise.) When spaces are important, it's good practice in TeX to escape all line endings this way.

Comment: That works - thank you for answering my newbie question. I can't remember things being that way in LaTeX, but then again it has been some time since I used it (never did anything in raw TeX).